# how to find phrases in dictionary from a list of phrases and creating dataframe with phrase found and count. duplicates should be counted

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

```
phrases = ['i am good', 'going to the market', 'eating cookies']

dictionary = {'http://www.firsturl.com': 'i am going to the market and tomorrow will be eating cookies',
             'http://www.secondurl.com': 'tomorrow is my birthday and i shall be', 
             'http://www.thirdurl.com': 'i am good and will go to sleep'}
```

> if there is at least a match:
>   expected output:

```
url                             phrasecount    phrase
http://www.firsturl.com         2              going to the market, eating cookies
http://www.thirdurl.com         1              i am good
```

If there is no match from all 3 urls the return just the first occurrence url with zero count and blank phrase
expected output:

```
url                            phrasecount    phrase
http://www.firsturl.com        0
```

Comment: Doesn't the output in first row in `phrase` column should be `going to the market, eating cookies`?

Comment: sure! corrected

Comment: so how does it work, must the phrase be exact? ```i am a good ``` does not perfectly match, even though u can pull out ```i am good``` from it?

Comment: @BerceyEfund  As @sammywemmy suggested, What about the phrase `i am good`? How'd it got included in the output?

Comment: @ShubhamSharma I believe that was just a typo as it doesn't match the expected output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setup the initial dataframe `df` from corresponding `dictionary`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'urls': list(dictionary.keys()), 'strings': list(dictionary.values())})
pattern = '|'.join(phrases)
```

Process the dataframe:

```
s = df.pop('strings').str.findall(pattern)
df = df.assign(phrasecount=s.str.len(), phrase=s.map(', '.join))
df = df.drop_duplicates(subset='phrasecount') if df['phrasecount'].eq(0).all() else df[df['phrasecount'].ne(0)]
```

Result:

```
# print(df)

                      urls  phrasecount                               phrase
0  http://www.firsturl.com            2  going to the market, eating cookies
2  http://www.thirdurl.com            1                            i am good
```

Comment: ----> 4     pd.DataFrame(dictionary).T.reset_index()

Comment: getting error:
ValueError: If using all scalar values, you must pass an index

Comment: @BerceyEfund Ok I see you updated your dictionary, I have to edit the answer.

Comment: @BerceyEfund Edited the answer.

Comment: Thats the correct output. basically count how many times the phrases in the list occur in the text.

Comment: This is not counting the phrases but counting the letters

Comment: @BerceyEfund This is counting the phrases in your `phrase list`

Comment: @BerceyEfund I've edited the answer to make it more concise.

Comment: its counting letters not phrases

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215182/discussion-between-shubham-sharma-and-bercey-efund).